# Upper bound for the number of hamilton cycles in a cubic graph

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Wikipedia states, that it has been proven, that there are at most $1.276^n$ hamilton cycles
 in a cubic graph with $n$ nodes. This upper bound is not valid for $n=6$. The values I
 found out using an online calculator are $(H(n)$ is the true maximum number of hamilton-cycles) :

$$ n\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  ceil(1.276^n)  \ \ \ \ \ \ \   H(n)$$

$$ 4\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 3\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 3 $$
$$ 6\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 5\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 6 $$
$$ 8\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 8\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 6 $$
$$10\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 12\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 12$$
$$12\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 19\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 16$$
$$14\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 31\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 24$$
$$16\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 50\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 32$$
$$18\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 81\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 64$$

My questions :

- Are my values for $H(n)$ correct ?
- Is the upper bound valid for $n>6$ ? (I could not open the link wikipedia shows)
- Upto which $n$ is the true value $H(n)$ known ?
- Is the upper bound asymptotically sharp; does 
  $$\lim_{n->\infty} \frac{1.276^n}{H(n)}=1$$ hold ?

Comment: I used the ceil-function (rounding up). If I would use the truncate-function, only the values for $n\ge 12$ (and for $n=8$) would be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I get the same values for $H(n)$
- The bound in the paper is an asymptotical bound, that is the number of Hamiltonian cycles in a cubic graph is $O({1.276}^n).$
- I don't think $H(n) \sim {1.276}^n.$  If this were known, the authors would state the result involving $\Theta$ not $O$

The mentioned paper can be found [here](http://www.google.si/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.inf.ethz.ch%2Fpersonal%2Fgebauerh%2Fnewreport&ei=CYROVLa7IInXPIiRgMAH&usg=AFQjCNEKcOc5eY-w3LnKSr6YMQ04ReKt0Q&sig2=SP82CSrTdGsp5PB-5TlWLQ&bvm=bv.77880786,d.ZWU&cad=rja).

Comment: So, $H(n)<=1.276^n$ need not be true for all $n>6$ ? (Since the bound is only asymptotical)

Comment: Exactly. What you do know though is that the limit you mention is $\leq c$ for some $c > 0.$

Comment: @Peter I forgot to mention that in this context $c$ can as well be infinity.